# How to make a radio button using MIGX extra for ModX Revolution

Tags: modx-revolution

It doesn't look like there's much information on this out there. I'm having trouble creating a MIGX template variable in ModX Revolution that includes a radio button array (if one is selected, then the others aren't). Here's what I got so far:

```
[{"caption":"Info", "fields": [
  {"field":"name","caption":"Name"},
  {"field":"description","caption":"Description", "inputTVtype":"richtext"},
  {"field":"price","caption":"Price"},
  {"field":"ticket_status","caption":"Ticket Status","inputTVtype":"radio","inputOptionValues":"On Sale==onsale||Off Sale==offsale||Sold Out==soldout"}
]}
]
```

So the end result should look like:

Name:
Description:(text editor)
Price:
Ticket Status:
   radio button for On Sale
   radio button for Off Sale
   radio button for Sold Out
   (only one should be able to be selected at a time)

Is this possible? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ticket_status` use this `"inputTVtype":"option"` instead `"inputTVtype":"radio"`.

Comment: Sorry for the (massive) delay in accepting this answer.